# ACL Permissions

Tags: permissions

I need to limit the access to a group of individuals for certain users. This is what I have done.

1. Created a user role called Student Interactions
2. Created a group called student Interactions Access and added the users that should have access to this role.
3. Assigned the student interactions access group to the Student Interactions ACL Role.
4. Added an ACL For the student interactions role to view a new group I created called current students.

When I log in as one of the users assigned to the student interactions access group I can still see all users, not just the ones in the current student group. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have turned off 'View all Contacts' permission for the user role. This permission over-rides all ACL rule. You can check permissions by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Users and permissions >> Permissions (Access Control) >> Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla Access Control.

HTH

Pradeep